# How to get the html which is loaded in a div dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am creating a website in which the html is loaded when the user clicks on the side bar subpages. onclick function is used in the side bar. Then I am creating a div as base where i am loading the pages.

I want to somehow know what html or function is present in base div after it has been loaded. I have tried the following but I am getting empty data.

Is there any way to extract what html is loaded or a function after it has been loaded?

```
function checkhtml()
{
   alert(JSON.stringify($('#base').val()));

}
```

HTML

```
 <div id="base" class="col pt-2" style="overflow: auto;">

      </div>
```

JS

```
function load_table1() {
  $('#base').load('../htmls/table1', function () {
    gettable1();
  });
}

function load_table2() {
  $('#base').load('../htmls/table2.html', function () {
    gettable2();
  });
}
```

Comment: You want to get the html in `<div id=base`?  Then use `.html()` not `.val()` - .val will give you the value of an input.  You also don't want to stringify it as it's already a string `alert($("#base").html())`

Comment: val is for input not for element u should use html

Answer (score 0):

The callback arguments of the `load()` function receive the responseText of the request. You can use this to check the content which is added to the DOM:

```js
function checkhtml(html) {
  console.log('The following HTML was added:');
  console.log(html);
}

function load_table1() {
  $('#base').load('../htmls/table1', function(html) {
    checkhtml(html); 
    gettable1();
  });
}

function load_table2() {
  $('#base').load('../htmls/table2.html', function(html) {
    checkhtml(html)
    gettable2();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why to you want to *extract* it? You are putting it here yourself, so you already have this value.

jQuery's [load](https://api.jquery.com/load/) callback gives you the value that was loaded :

```
$("#base").load( "../htmls/table2.html", function( response, status, xhr ) {

     console.log("This data was loaded : ", response);  

});
```